# Firebase: Removing an Object from an Array

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

i'm trying to delete an specific object from an array in Firestore via SwiftUI. The following function deletes the whole watchlist. What am I missing?

```
func removeFromWatchlist() {
        
    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        let docRef = db.collection("user").document(uid)     // company.symbol = "AAPL"
        docRef.updateData(["watchlist": FieldValue.arrayRemove([company.symbol])]) { error in
            if error == nil {
                print("Successful deleted array")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Firestore structure:
[image: Firestore structure]

Comment: Watchlist looks like a map of objects rather than an array. Have you tried deleting the key itself? i.e. `updateData(["watchlist.AAPL": FieldValue.delete()])` (I'm not a Swift dev, so the syntax may be off, but that's the gist of it).

Comment: It is a map not an array in firebase. Array has indexes 0-11 not names like on image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an item from an array with `FieldValue.arrayRemove` you must specify the exact, complete data that is stored in the array.

Assuming your `company.symbol` is `AAPL`, the call `FieldValue.arrayRemove([company.symbol]` removes that exact string from the array - not the `AAPL` key that you have with an object under it.

You'll have to read the entire array from the document into you application code, remove it there, and then write the entire modified array back to the document.

Comment: Probably also worth highlighting that `arrayUnion` and `arrayRemove` will replace all non-array data with an array containing the given elements (for `arrayUnion`) or an empty array (for `arrayRemove`).